# C++ replace all occurances of character in string

Tags: c++

I have a program in C++ in which all the input into the program has underscores('_') instead of spaces. I'm trying to replace all the underscores which spaces(' '). I tried using std::replace but I keep getting errors, I'm not sure where I'm getting it wrong.

```
int main()
{   
    string j = "This_is_a_test";

    j = std::replace( j.begin(), j.end(), '_', ' ');

    // I'm trying to get: This is a test from 'j',  
}
```

This is returning an error when I try compiling:

> conversion from `void' to non-scalar type`std::basic_string, std::allocator >' requested

Comment: Maybe read some `std::replace` documentation?

Comment: Plus one: this is forgiveable if your normal language is Java.

Comment: @Bathsheba What? Java people don't know to look up documentation? Interesting...

Comment: Regular expression people *certainly* don't.

Comment: @MelvinRufetu See the duplicate linked above. That has solutions to your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::replace` works on iterators, so it modifies the string directly, without a necessary return value. Use

```
std::replace(j.begin(), j.end(), '_', ' ');
```

instead.

Answer (score 1):

`std::replace` returns `void`.

You can't assign `void` to `std::string`.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to use :

```
 std::replace( j.begin(), j.end(), '_', ' ');
 cout<<j;
```